# How to stop setTimeout that was started outside the function that detects if the form was submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My setTimeout starts when the page is loaded, I need to stop it as soon as the user clicks the button and submit the form, the variable seems to get lost and I can't stop, any tips?

my code

```
$(function() {

        function atualiza(){
            $.get('online.php?p=SMS', 
            function(resultado){
                $('#onlineagora').html(resultado);
            });
        }

        timer1 = setTimeout('atualiza()', 850);
            
        $('#formsms').submit(function( event ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'aguardesms.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: $('#formsms').serialize(),
                success: function(content){
                    clearTimeout(timer1);//STOP ATUALIZA
                    $("#DisplayDiv").html(content);
                }  
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Comment: unsure how the variable gets lost. Are you sure the success method is called? Shouldn't clearTimeout(timer1); be outside the Ajax request to make sure that it cancels the timer before the Ajax call is returned?

Comment: Just put `let` in front of `timer1 = setTimeout('atualiza()', 850);` for fun. ;)

Comment: @epascarello yes the method is called successfully but the timer does not stop

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it does not stop and remains active

Comment: does it actually working with singlequotes function covered :)

Comment: Are you sure the timer did not go off BEFORE you submitted and the Ajax request is already active?

Comment: I just noticed.`setTimeout('atualiza()', 850);`. You are passing a string instead of a function. Is there something else calling `actualiza` ?

Comment: @MetByrdy like this? let timer1 = setTimeout(atualiza(), 850);

Comment: `setTimeout(atualiza, 850)`

Comment: Do you realize that timer is running 850 milliseconds.... So it is running basically as soon as the page is ready. You must be a fast clicker.... So you have under a second to click the button after the page has rendered the elements. I doubt you are clicking before that code has run.

Comment: You can find out example usages here in this page : 
https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: put clearTimeout(timer1);//STOP ATUALIZA  before ajax

Comment: @Frenchy don`t work too it keeps running, is necessary that when entering the page he does this verification and at the same time verify that the form has been filled out, if it is completed for the timer and the rest of the process continues.

Comment: Based on the strong assumption that the timeout was simply not running... It is something else that happens. `the rest of the process continues` is quite unclear.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette rest of process is load an page on div with ajax, but i need make post request second by second for check if my user is online, when form pressed i want stop this requests and go to next page

Comment: `i need make post request second by second for check if my user is online`... So there is a `setInterval()` somewhere?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Nothing changes if I change the function to make the post, the problem is that I have to stop the timer within the function to check if the form has been submitted, the function of the timer that makes requests every second is outside that function that check the form, that is, it makes no difference, I need to know how to call the functions correctly.

Comment: So you want to stop the requests every seconds? Anyway, I guess you have to edit your question with a bit more code and the relevant HTML.

Comment: i need stop requests when form submitted, while not submitted i want post requests with atualiza() function

Answer (score 0):

solved using setInterval/clearInterval

```
var timer1 = setInterval(atualiza, 850);
function atualiza(){
    $.get('online.php?p=SMS', 
    function(resultado){

    });
}
$('#formsms').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
clearInterval(timer1);
$.ajax({
        url: 'aguardesms.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $('#formsms').serialize(),
        success: function(content){
            $("#DisplayDiv").html(content);
        }  
    });
});
```